# How to Parse a String to get a Measurement (Opposite of MeasurementFormatter)

Tags: ios, cocoa, foundation

Apple has provided us a fairly nice way to get from a Measurement to a string:

`MeasurementFormatter().string( from: measurement )`

I'm trying to go the opposite direction: given a string provided by a user, I'd like to parse it and turn it into a Measurement object. [E.g., convert "2cm" into `Measurement(value: 2.0, unit: UnitLength.centimeters)`]

Does Apple provide any help here, or does anybody know of a library that does this already?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189495/initializing-a-unit-from-string